# How to avoid overbooking/overselling items between cart and payment

Tags: mysql, database, paypal, database-schema, payment

I have an online registration site where people can register and pay for a list of programs. It works like a cart where they add all the programs they want to register for and then "checkout"

I validate that the attendees meet the age requirements and there is room in the program before adding them into the cart. However I do not add them to the program or make any changes to the database yet.

When they click 'register' I process their cart and send the user to paypal to authorize. I receive the authorization from paypal and then write to my database to register and pay their programs at the same time I charge the payment.

However, If 2 people have the same program/item in their list and it happens to be the last one. I am not sure how to deal with this.

Do I validate there is room in all the programs again between authorization and accepting the payment or do I add a processing field to the registration table in my database? Or is there a better way?

Here is an image of my schema.
[image]

Comment: I've been seeing movie ticket sales online use a "holding logic" once you express you want to buy the tickets, so before any payment information is collected.  They hold the tickets from 5 to maybe 15 minutes.  Would some kind of hold logic work for your case?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking maybe i need another table to `hold reservations` until they are processed. I would then need to change my `spaceAvailable` call to add the `hold reservations`. This is just a guess on my part and I'm sure there is a best practices or design pattern to do this right which I can't find anywhere. I'm not sure how to delete the holds consistently too.

Comment: Another option I think might work is a `processing` field in the pivot table.